# Changing the default offset value for histogram aggregations.

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way which I can change the offset value for aggregations. Now when I give histogram aggregation, elasticsearch automatically determines the start value of the aggregation. Now I need to modify the default offset value. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by start value of aggreagtion. Can you please specify?

Answer (score 2):

You can use scripting for that. An example on this for histogram aggregation would be like below:

```
{
"aggs": {
        "histogram-aggs": {
            "histogram": {
                "field": "your-field",
                "interval": 1000,
                "script": "_value + 2000"
            }     
        }   
    }
}
```

This would change the default offset value for the histogram aggregation by 2000. You can find a demonstration of the same [here](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-scripting-aggregations)